# Searching JSON using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

```
  [
{"lastName":"Noyce","gender":"Male","patientID":19389,"firstName":"Scott","age":"53Y,"}, 
{"lastName":"noyce724","gender":"Male","patientID":24607,"firstName":"rita","age":"0Y,"}
]
```

Above is my JSON Data

```
  var searchBarInput = TextInput.value;

    for (i in recentPatientsList.length) {
     alert(recentPatientsList[i].lastName
    }
```

I am getting the alert for this. Now i have a TextInput which on typing should search the Json and yield me the result. I am searching for lastname value.

How would i take the value and search in my JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
var searchBarInput = TextInput.value;

for (i in recentPatientsList.length) {
 alert(recentPatientsList[i].lastName); // added the ) for you
}
```

is incorrect. What you should do to iterate over an array is:

```
for (var i = 0; i < recentPatientsList.length; ++i) {
  alert(recentPatientsList[i].lastName);
}
```

The "for ... in" mechanism isn't really for iterating over the indexed properties of an array.

Now, to make a comparison, you'd just look for the name in the text input to be equal to the "lastName" field of a list entry:

```
for (var i = 0; i < recentPatientsList.length; ++i) {
  if (searchBarInput === recentPatientsList[i].lastName) {
    alert("Found at index " + i);
  }
}
```

Comment: Will the alert yield me only the results which equal the last name.. to print those data should i use alert(recentPatientsList[i].lastName after the comparision.

Comment: The "alert()" is just there as an example. The point is that all you have to do is a simple comparison between the input value and the strings in your table; there's nothing magical about it.

Comment: *"The "for ... in" mechanism isn't really for iterating over the indexed properties of an array."* Although it's very useful for avoiding unnecessary loop iterations on sparse arrays. The OP's array isn't sparse, so simple loops are the best answer. For sparse arrays, `for..in` is the best answer but you must use `if (recentPatientList.hasOwnProperty(i) && String(Number(i)) === i)` to be sure you're sticking to just the entries in the array.

Comment: can you help me here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5766961/searching-for-character-in-json-using-javascript

Answer (score 1):

You should not use `for..in` to iterate over an array. Instead use a plain old for loop for that. To get objects matching the last name, filter the array.

```
var matchingPatients = recentPatientsList.filter(function(patient) {
    return patient.lastName == searchBarInput;
});
```