# Searching for character in JSON using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

```
[
{"lastName":"Noyce","gender":"Male","patientID":19389,"firstName":"Scott","age":"53Y,"}, 
{"lastName":"noyce724","gender":"Male","patientID":24607,"firstName":"rita","age":"0Y,"}
]
```

Comparing my input with the JSON.

```
for (var i = 0; i < recentPatientsList.length; ++i) {
  if (searchBarInput === recentPatientsList[i].lastName) {
    alert("Found at index " + i);
  }
}
```

With this i am able to see whether i match my input with the JSON. How can i get results of data whose last name starts with 'N' or given input.

Comment: Did you ask the same question twice??

Comment: not exactly, but its some what similar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you searchBarInput is equal to `"n"`, **Try this:**

```
var results = []; // initialize array of results
for (var i = 0; i < recentPatientsList.length; ++i) {
  if (recentPatientsList[i].lastName.indexOf(searchBarInput) == 0) {
    results.push(recentPatientsList[i].lastName);
  }
}
alert('Results: ' + results.toString());
```

Comment: Wbat does indexOf(inputControl) == 0 means? Why do we check with a Zero.

Comment: I don't know what `inputControl` is but `indexOf()` returns the index of the matching string -- `0` if the match is at the beginning.

Comment: its a textInput... and if i have to match for n in any part of the word... what should i use.

Comment: If there is a match, then the `indexOf()` method will return a positive number (or zero) -- and `-1` if there is no match.  So you can check to see if the result is `>= 0` or `!= -1`.